# Make builder not wait for element to load

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, flutter-pageview

I have a very large list of small cards. And it freeze app for about second on initial load. It's really annoying cause there a **PageView** with multiple of pages with small cards.

I am using this package to create wrapped list of cards. But it's still not enough to reduce lag.

```yaml
dynamic_layouts:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:flutter/packages.git
      path: packages/dynamic_layouts
```

Code:

```dart
// Inside main widgetState builder
PageView.builder(
  controller: _pageController,
  preloadPagesCount: 0,
  itemCount: _data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => _PageViewElement(_data.values.elementAt(index)),
);
```

```dart
// Inside _PageViewElementState builder
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    DynamicSliverGrid(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithWrapping(),
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) => GestureDetector( 
          onTap: () async => toggle(_data.elementAt(index)),
          child: MySmallCard(_data.elementAt(index)),
        ),
        childCount: _data.length,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Tried to use [**PreloadPageView**](https://pub.dev/packages/preload_page_view) to cache pages but it didn't help and only increased initial lag.

Comment: I would suggest to load the data on separate isolate and see if there is performance improvement. Flutter by default does all the calculation on the main isolate and having to iterate over few thousand items (maybe decoding them as well) could be time consuming.

Comment: Data is parsed on app start. And my test are show that is problem with just displaying large amount of widgets at the same time. I really want something to build them on the go so new widget will show up then it's rendered (or something I don't really know how it's working on low level).